# Any way to login to Elasticsearch using terminal?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new at Elasticsearch and am basically working around the security aspects of it. So after defining the user-roles and creating new users, whenever I want to run a curl command using terminal, I have to specify the user credentials like,

```
-u {username}:{password}
```

So, is there any way to login to the localhost so that I enter the credentials one time only and after that I can simply run the commands without entering the credentials?

I am using the basic license of Elasticsearch.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the netrc feature provided by curl. You basically store the credentials in a file and use `-n` flag so curl accesses creds from that file.

Reference: https://everything.curl.dev/usingcurl/netrc